# deselect silverlight TreeViewItem on reselection

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

Once we select TreeViewItem, how can we can again deselect it?

TreeViewItem.IsSelected event is not called again if TreeViewItem is already selected.

I need this behavior on reselecting node in TreeView.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue with Treeview control, you need to do workaround for the same.

Check this url
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/36aca7f7-0b47-488b-8e16-840b86addfa3/

Comment: siverlight tree doesnt have TreeItem attached property